# liferay page layout thumbnails not showing up

Tags: url, layout, liferay-6

The issue is that I am not able to see thumbnails of the Page layouts. I am working on Liferay Portal EE 6.1.20.

When I go to Manage -> Page Layout, I cannot see the thumbnails.

Few things

1. I am not using OOB Liferay, it is a custom solution where Liferay is bundled as a custom portal solution
2. This thing works fine in Liferay OOB, so there must be some configuration issue
3. I tried to debug with Firebug and it is able to fetch the image from the URL specified.
4. The context path is changed from `/` to `/portal`
5. The generated image URL is like this `/portal/layouttpl/custom/1_2_columns_ii.png`. This is also not accessible from the browser itself.
6. The other URLS like `/portal/html` or `/portal/wap/` working fine. Only from `/portal/layouttpl` does not allow to access static resources.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 3):

It might be worth checking the file permissions of the images. In my Liferay *development enviroment*, I have all of my images set to 777:

```
user@ubuntu:/usr/liferay/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/layouttpl/custom$ ll *.png
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1801 Apr  2  2012 1_2_1_columns.png*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1798 Apr  2  2012 1_2_columns_ii.png*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1793 Apr  2  2012 1_2_columns_i.png*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1425 Apr  2  2012 1_column.png*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1923 Apr  2  2012 2_2_columns.png*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1718 Apr  2  2012 2_columns_iii.png*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1735 Apr  2  2012 2_columns_ii.png*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1618 Apr  2  2012 2_columns_i.png*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1852 Apr  2  2012 3_columns.png*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1740 Apr  2  2012 freeform.png*
```

Comment: Thanks Rhod, I am on Windows and file permissions are just fine like other files, so it might not be a permission issue here!

Comment: Another suggestion would be to modify your liferay-layout-templates.xml (mine is located in /usr/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF), change the thumbnail-paths to match your structure, e.g. <thumbnail-path>/layouttpl/standard/exclusive.png</thumbnail-path> would become <thumbnail-path>portal/layouttpl/standard/exclusive.png</thumbnail-path>. As you mention in your question, it looks like something needs to be configured for your layouts to recognise the path, so this solution might only be a quick fix.

Comment: Nope, I cannot do that. /portal is my portal context, so in any case Liferay is attaching that for me. if I would add that explicitly, for me it would be 2 times. like /portal/portal/layout. This will be incorrect!

Comment: Not really sure then Felix. I see you're using Enterprise Edition, if you're still entitled to support from the Liferay team, perhaps it might worth opening a ticket with them? Good luck :)

Comment: One more thing, have you set your portal.ctx in portal-ext.properties? http://www.liferay.com/de/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Changing+context+path+of+portal

Comment: Oh yes, I followed the same wiki!, may be checking with Liferay will be a good point though!